# InAndOut widget, having the same option multiple times for z3c.form

Tags: jquery, widget, plone, zope, z3c.form

Plone 4.1. I am creating a control widget for constructing a form (kind of PloneFormGen for ad hoc purposes). The user is allowed to pick different blocks for their form and reorder them.

Available options include:

```
Text block
Table block
Accordion block
```

And then you should be able to produce a list like:

```
Text block 1
Text block 2
Accordion block 
Text block 3
```

Out of them. Basically selecting items, but with an option to select the same item multiple times.

What would be a good widget / approach to create this kind of a selector?

Comment: I'm looking for something very similar, did you came up with something?

Comment: Is it available somewhere? :)